# Create local administrator user account fails in Intune

Tags: powershell, intune

The PowerShell script below works fine when I run it manually in a machine, but it won't run when deployed using Intune. It simply shows an error.

I have deployed this script using Intune with these settings -
(1) Run this script using the logged on credentials: **No**. (2)
Enforce script signature check: **No**. (3)
Run script in 64 bit PowerShell Host: **No**

Tested the script in a Windows 10 computer by starting CMD as admin, it works fine. Creates the local account if it does not exists, if it exists it changes the password.

```
PS> PowerShell -Ex ByPass scriptname.ps1
```

I am not able to find any event log (under DeviceManagement-Enterprise-Diagnostics-Provider) or error under MDMDiagnostics logs in the Intune enrolled Windows 10 computer.

```PowerShell
$ExpectedLocalUser = "SUPERMAN"
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "P@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force

Function Create_LocalAdmin
{

    New-LocalUser $ExpectedLocalUser -Password $Password -FullName "Local Admin" -Description "Local Administrator account."
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $ExpectedLocalUser
    Set-LocalUser -Name $ExpectedLocalUser -PasswordNeverExpires:$true
}

Try

{

    ## Catch if not found
    $LocaAdminUser = Get-LocalUser -Name $ExpectedLocalUser -ErrorAction Stop 

    ## If an account is found update the password
    Set-LocalUser -Name $ExpectedLocalUser -Password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires:$true

}

Catch

{

    Create_LocalAdmin

}
```

Comment: "Run script in 64 bit PowerShell Host: **No**" <-- why would you want to run it as a 32-bit process?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I can try running it as a 64 bit process. Didn't have any problem with other scripts which are in 32 bit mode.

Comment: What is the exact error you're seeing? As sidenote: better use single quote characters `'` around the password when converting it to secure string. It may have characters like the backtick or dollar sign in it that otherwise need to be escaped.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the object and use that as `-Member` for the `Add-LocalGroupMember` cmdlet? `$newUser = New-LocalUser -Name = $ExpectedLocalUser ...` or even directly pipe it through: `New-LocalUser -Name = $ExpectedLocalUser ... | Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators"`

Answer (score 0):

@mathias-r-jessen Suggestion worked. Changed to start PS in 64 bit host, and it worked.

[image]